# whats Best structure of Array of directory tree using less characters for storing in DB

Tags: php, arrays, directory-structure

i am trying to find the Best structure of Array to store the directory tree in mysql field, so that it uses less characters.

i am converting the directory tree in to an array and then using json_encode to convert it to string and then store that array in db.

my question is which array structure is best , if i have to create a directory tree again using ul and li on html from the same array.

Array Structure 1:

```
Array
(
    [directory1\file1.jpg] => 197602
    [directory1\file2.jpg] => 274893
    [directory2\file1.txt] => 41
    [directory2\file2.txt] => 41
    [directory2\sub-directory1\file1.txt] => 47
    [directory2\sub-directory1\file2.txt] => 41
    [directory2\sub-directory1\file3.txt] => 47
    [file1.txt] => 41
    [file2.txt] => 47
)
```

Array Structure 2:

```
Array
(
    [directory1] Array(
                        [file1.jpg] => 197602
                        [file2.jpg] => 274893
                        )

    [directory2]Array(
                        [file1.txt] => 41
                        [file2.txt] => 41
                        [sub-directory1]Array(
                                                [file1.txt] => 41
                                                [file2.txt] => 44
                                                [file3.txt] => 54
                                                )

                    )
    [file1.txt] => 41
    [file2.txt] => 47
)
```

or any other method ?

Comment: how about `(id, parent_id, filename)`?

Comment: can you show some example ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Similar to how file system keeps track of files:

```
id parent_id name            size
-------------------------------------
0  null      /               null
1  0         directory1      null
2  0         directory2      null
3  0         file1.txt       41
4  0         file2.txt       47
5  1         file1.jpg       197602
6  1         file2.jpg       274893
7  2         file1.txt       41
8  2         file2.txt       41
9  2         sub-directory1  null
10 9         file1.txt       41
11 9         file2.txt       44
12 9         file3.txt       54
```

Comment: okie., thanks, just didnt understand the id part from your comment, will try it using array.

Comment: is it table structure for mysql ? or the array stucture. thanbks, i am looking for array structure.

Comment: @AMB, Sorry it's supposed to be a mysql table. If you need the entire tree in one record, your 2nd structure is more appropriate because it uses less space, and is easier to build the nested HTML lists.